# "Build Warning: Layout 'none' requested in feed.xml does not exist."

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I've solved the error message

> "Build Warning: Layout 'none' requested in feed.xml does not exist."

Removing three lines at the head of current `feed.xml` file. Is good solution? Whats wrong to remove these three lines?

```
---
layout: none
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <title>{{ site.title | xml_escape }}</title>
    <description>{{ site.description | xml_escape }}</description>
    <link>{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/</link>
    <atom:link href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <pubDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>Jekyll v{{ jekyll.version }}</generator>
    {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
      <item>
        <title>{{ post.title | xml_escape }}</title>
        <description>{{ post.content | xml_escape }}</description>
        <pubDate>{{ post.date | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
        <link>{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}</guid>
        {% for tag in post.tags %}
        <category>{{ tag | xml_escape }}</category>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for cat in post.categories %}
        <category>{{ cat | xml_escape }}</category>
        {% endfor %}
      </item>
    {% endfor %}
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct expression is :

```
---
layout: null
---
```

Comment: Thak you so much! I created a none.html template. Usesless! Thank you for this right solution.